# google-apis-explorer youtubeanalytics api returns forbidden to authorized CMS user credentials

Tags: python, youtube-api

https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports returns 403-forbidden in api explorer and python api when queried by user with valid Youtube CMS credentials for that content owner. Message is "You do not have permission to execute this method." (reports method)
In Python I have a valid Oauth token. I am using the current api and example python code, modified for content owner and video data.

```
  partner_name = "xxx"
  vid = "--LFViiCKlM"
  start_date = "2019-04-01"
  end_date = "2019-07-01"

  youtubeAnalytics = get_service()
  execute_api_request(
        youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
        ids="contentOwner=={}".format(partner_name),
        metrics="views",
        dimensions="day",
        startDate=start_date,
        endDate=end_date,
        maxResults=1200,
        sort="day",
        filters="video=={}".format(vid)
  )
```

These parameters worked in version 1 of the YouTube Analytics api and appear to be correct based on current docs.

In API explorer I am signed in to Google with the same credentials and browser for both CMS and API explorer.

I have not used this api for approx 15 months. Has the Google/CMS permission structure changed? Is some new permission required to use the API?